# Why does Jenkins use a different temp folder when launched from jar or from a service?

Tags: jenkins, getgauge

I have been trying to launch a testing app from Jenkins . Initially I started Jenkins from the Jar file and things were working fine.

This was the console output:

```
Started by user ABC
Building in workspace C:\MyDir
[xyz] $ cmd /c call C:\Users\usrname\AppData\Local\Temp\hudson2329759222967199349.bat
...
```

Now when I start Jenkins as a Windows service

```
Started by user ABC
Building in workspace C:\MyDIr
[xyz] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hudson4009309858990093371.bat
C:\MyDir>gauge specs 
Failed to start gauge API: Plugin 'java' not installed on following locations : [C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins]
```

Why does it run it from a different temp folder?
I tried rectifying things by adding the AppData\Local\Temp path to jenkins.xml

```
<executable>java</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle
    "-Dhudson.model.DirectoryBrowserSupport.CSP=sandbox allow-scripts; default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' ; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"
    -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Temp" 
  -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

If it helps: Jenkins is installed in C:\Users\username.jenkins
The Jenkins page just refuses to load. 
What should I do?

Comment: Ok. 1 part of the problem was the enter instead of space before -jar. Putting "-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" at least lets Jenkins execute. Even if the result is still "Failed to start gauge API: Plugin 'java' not installed on following locations"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Local System` account in Windows uses its profile from `C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile`. `temp` etc folders are refered from this location when running the process under `Local System`. Refer to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/112927/where-does-the-local-system-account-store-its-personal-files) for details on this.

In your scenario, you have the below options:

- Run you Jenkins job under a dedicated account, and provision your agent to have `gauge` and `plugins` installed for that account.
- Add `gauge --install-all` as a task in your job. This will ensure that all the plugins required by the project are installed.